# Passing arbitrary-templated vector as function argument C++

Tags: c++, vector

Sorry if this is something trivial, and it also may not be of huge importance, but I'm just curious and I couldn't find an answer yet.

In C++ I'm creating functions to evaluate some stuff in a vector, the result is double, but I want the function to work for both vector and vector. The solution I go for is overload, as in this showcase simple example:

```
double silly_example(vector<int> &vec){
    return vec[0] + vec[1];
}
double silly_example(vector<double> &vec){
    return vec[0] + vec[1];
}
```

However, it is true for all functions that there is **no** difference in the body of the overloaded functions. As said, the result is double, the calculations use double. If a vector is passed, the int members are converted to double anyway.
So is there a way to somehow avoid having to overload each of these functions and just tell the compiler that the template here doesn't matter as long as its something numeric? I wish for something like:

```
double wished_form(vector<auto> &vec){
    return (double) vec[0] + (double) vec[1];
}
```

I know the auto doesn't work like that, this is just to showcase what I mean: is there some way like this to combine the two overloaded functions into one?

Thanks and sorry if this is trivial or silly.

Comment: This is literally why templates exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy:

```
template <class T>
double wished_form(const vector<T>& vec) {
    return (double) vec[0] + (double) vec[1];
}
```

If `T` is not convertible to `double`, a compile-time error will occur.

Comment: Clear. Simple. Easy. Nice. But not extensible to more complicated cases. By `#include`ing `type_traits` and replacing the return type with `typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertable<T,double>::value, double>::type` you get something that (a) is nauseating, (b) also works, and (c) models how you go about enforcing conditions during template processing (in c++11 style as that's what I've been writing recently).

Comment: @dmckee: `auto wished_form(const vector<T>& vec) -> decltype((double) vec[0] + (double) vec[1])` :)

Comment: @jarod42 `template<class T> auto wished_form( T const& vec ) RETURNS( (double)vec[0] + (double)vec[1] )` :p